# $n$-th derivative of $(x^2-1)^n$ has distinct real roots in $[-1,1]$.

Tags: analysis, derivatives

For $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, let
$$f(x) = (x^2-1)^n .$$
Show that the $n$-th derivative $f^{(n)}$ has distinct real roots in $[-1,1]$.
I have no idea about the problem. Could I have a hint?

Comment: Rolle's theorem, and "for $0 \leqslant k \leqslant n$, the $k$-th derivative of $(x^2-1)^n$ has [at least] $k$ distinct roots in $(-1,1)$".

Comment: To add to Daniel's suggestion: $f^{(k)}(1) = f^{(k)}(-1) = 0 $, for $k < n$..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=(x^2-1)^n$ is an even function with two zeroes of multiplicity $n$ at $x=\pm 1$. It follows that $f'(x)$ has two zeroes of multiplicity $n-1$ at $x=\pm 1$ and a zero at $x=0$. By Rolle's theorem, $f''(x)$ has a zero in $(-1,0)$ and a zero in $(0,1)$. Moreover, there are two zeroes of multiplicity $n-2$ at $x=\pm 1$. Continuing that way, we may see that $f^{(n-1)}(x)$ has $(n-1)$ distinct zeroes in $(-1,1)$ and two simple zeroes at $x=\pm 1$, so $f^{(n)}(x)$ has $n$ distinct zeroes in $(-1,1)$ as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:

You can use induction to show that the $k$-th derivative has $k$ real roots in $(-1,1)$ .

Comment: can somebody explain the downvote?

Comment: ok no problem, don't worry about it:)
i just wanted to have the chance to learn from my mistakes